# NodeJS running Shell commands in a for loop while maintaining execution order

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I'm experimenting with shell commands in node using `exec`, but the code isn't executing in the order I'm expecting.

This is the code.

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');

var newDataArray = []

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    console.log(i)
    let printHelloCommand = 'echo hello' + i;

    exec(printHelloCommand, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err)
        } else {
            newDataArray.push(i)
            console.log(newDataArray)
            console.log("------")
        }
    })
}
console.log("Printing array")
console.log(newDataArray)
```

This is the output I'm receiving.

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
Printing array
[]
[ 10 ]
------
[ 10, 10 ]
------
[ 10, 10, 10 ]
------
[ 10, 10, 10, 10 ]
------
[ 10, 10, 10, 10, 10 ]
------
[ 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10 ]
------
[ 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10 ]
------
[ 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10 ]
------
[ 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10 ]
------
[ 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10 ]
```

The code execution is all over the place. The `console.log(i)` in line 9 is printing fully, when it should only print once a loop. Then the execution skips to the end of the file to print on empty array, and the only value being pushed into the array is `10`, even though it should be pushing every value of `i` from 1-10 into the array.

How do I resolve this? I tried promises from the blue-bird library, but it doesn't seem to resolve my issue.

Comment: In JavaScript, members declared with `var` don't have block scope. Those declared with `let` do have block scope. That should help explain why `newDataArray` is populated entirely with tens.

Comment: The other thing you need to realise is that the `for` loop executes synchronously while the `(err) => {...}` callback executes asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to execute callback style inside for loop synchronously which is giving unexpected results. Try the promise version like this

```
const util = require("util");
const execAsync = util.promisify(require("child_process").exec);

(async() => {
  const newDataArray = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    console.log(i);
    const printHelloCommand = `echo hello${ i}`;
    await execAsync(printHelloCommand);
    newDataArray.push(i);
    console.log(newDataArray);
    console.log("------");
  }
  console.log("Printing array");
  console.log(newDataArray);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work because this doesn't work (`var` creates a variable whose scope is outside the loop which is accessed by all of the asynchronous operations callbacks):

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() { console.log(i); }, 1000);
}
```

By declaring the `i` variable as `let` the scope becomes the block inside of the loop and this will create a distinct variable for each iteration of the loop (every asynchronous operation callback has its own variable):

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() { console.log(i); }, 1000);
}
```

This will fix your code.